# Having trouble adding a space after a period in a python string

Tags: python

I have to write a code to do 2 things:

1. Compress more than one occurrence of the space character into one.
2. Add a space after a period, if there isn't one.

For example:

```
input> This   is weird.Indeed
output>This is weird. Indeed.
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
def correction(string):
    list=[]
    for i in string:
        if i!=" ":
            list.append(i)
        elif i==" ":
            k=i+1
            if k==" ":
               k=""
            list.append(i)

    s=' '.join(list)
    return s

strn=input("Enter the string: ").split()
print (correction(strn))
```

This code takes any input by the user and removes all the extra spaces,but it's not adding the space after the period(I know why not,because of the split function it's taking the period and the next word with it as one word, I just can't figure how to fix it)

This is a code I found online:

```
import re
def correction2(string):
  corstr = re.sub('\ +',' ',string)
  final = re.sub('\.','. ',corstr)
  return final

strn= ("This   is as   .Indeed")
print (correction2(strn))
```

The problem with this code is I can't take any input from the user. It is predefined in the program.
So can anyone suggest how to improve any of the two codes to do both the functions on ANY input by the user?

Comment: Your example doesn't match your question. There is only one leading `whitespace` character in your input. Not more than one.

Comment: My bad,sorry. I did add 3 spaces between this and is but they're not showing, I guess I need to check the formatting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you desire?

```
import re

def corr(s):
    return re.sub(r'\.(?! )', '. ', re.sub(r' +', ' ', s))

s = input("> ")
print(corr(s))
```

I've changed the regex to a lookahead pattern, take a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/fY9wM9/1).

---

**Edit: explain Regex as requested in comment**

[re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.sub) takes (at least) three arguments: The *Regex search pattern*, the *replacement* the matched pattern should be replaced with, and the string in which the replacement should be done.

What I'm doing here is two steps at once, I've been using the output of one function as input of another.
First, the inner `re.sub(r' +', ' ', s)` searches for multiple spaces (`r' +'`) in `s` to replace them with single spaces. Then the outer `re.sub(r'\.(?! )', '. ', ...)` looks for *periods without following space character* to replace them with `'. '`. I'm using a *negative lookahead pattern* to match only sections, that don't match the specified lookahead pattern (a normal space character in this case). You may want to [play around](https://regex101.com/r/fY9wM9/1) with this pattern, this may help understanding it better.

The `r` string prefix changes the string to a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) where backslash-escaping is disabled. Unnecessary in this case, but it's a habit of mine to use raw strings with regular expressions.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted from the second code! Thanks :) . Could you explain a bit what you did in the re.sub? (I'm new to python)

Comment: Thank you! I got it :D! . I have 2 questions though: 1.) Why did you put  ' r'\.(?!) ' instead of just ' r'\ '.  (I tried it, and it worked) ? 
2.) Can I use the 'r' string prefix always?

Comment: 1. `'\.(?! )'` matches only, if there is _no following space character_, so a `"Foo. Bar"` would not be changed to `"Foo.  Bar"`. Remove this in [the example](https://regex101.com/r/fY9wM9/1) and see the difference!
2. Yes, the `r` prefix works always.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For a more basic answer, without regex:

```
>>> def remove_doublespace(string):
...     if '  ' not in string:
...         return string
...     return remove_doublespace(string.replace('  ',' '))
...
>>> remove_doublespace('hi there  how    are   you.i am fine. '.replace('.', '. '))
'hi there how are you. i am fine. '
```

Answer (score 0):

You try the following code:

```
>>> s = 'This is weird.Indeed'
>>> def correction(s):
    res = re.sub('\s+$', '', re.sub('\s+', ' ', re.sub('\.', '. ', s)))
    if res[-1] != '.':
       res += '.'
    return res

>>> print correction(s)
This is weird. Indeed.

>>> s=raw_input()
hee   ss.dk
>>> s
'hee   ss.dk'
>>> correction(s)
'hee ss. dk.'
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit(I'm using python 3 ) :)?

Comment: So you only use `input` instead of `raw_input`.